# (Maximum subarray prob) After finding the maximum subarray,how there is still n-1 choose 2 subarrays are left to consider?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force, big-o

I'm reading Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition by clrs, and on page 69(Maximum subarray problem) in the paragraph..."A transformation",it's stated that n-1 choose 2 = Theta (n^2) subarrays are still needed to check.I don't understand that,as we already found the maximum subarray,then why do we need to further check subarrays and that too.. why from n-1 choose 2?we are choosing subsequences...not two days...!

Comment: While it may be clear to you what the book says on page 69 it isn't to most of us here (most likely everyone, considering the book title). Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Paul  the book is the world-renowned algorithm book

Comment: @codecrazer I'm pretty sure I've stumbled upon more than one book with that title. In either way, OP should still include the relevant parts here.

Comment: @Paul sorry about that....Actually, it is my first question here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the book, and found that maybe you don't really get the point of the question, the question can be transformed to the famous subarray problem.

The subarray problem is given an array, find the the subarray which has the maximun sum of all its element.

So, the brute force algorithm in the books means that, you can check all start point and end point of the subarray, which is n-1 choose 2, because we have n-1 elements in the array, and we can choose any of two to be begin and end,
so the complexity is O(n^2), hope this help you!

reference: Introduction to algorithms 3rd edition

Comment: so, you mean.. that the n choose 2 mentioned for the total number of pair of dates has n elements to choose from and after the discussion of "A transformation" we are choosing subarrays from n-1 elements?

Comment: You have to read through all the text, we have n days, but we only have n-1 change of the day.